# configuration of a cronTrigger (with opensymphony quartz)

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger, opensymphony

I have a web app that has to do something every, let's say first day of every month.

It's a GWT application divided into 4 projects (if that ever matters) and I added these jars using Maven (which updated my pom.xml):

opensymphony quartz 1.6.3
commons-collections

Since I am already using Spring, I followed this tutorial ([Tutorial in French](http://blogperso.univ-rennes1.fr/yoann.lecuyer/index.php/post/2008/05/06/Utilisation-de-Spring-Quartz))

and added what's written in the tutorial in my application-context.xml file.

At compile time, no problem, but at runtime, I have this error :

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: Error 500 Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactory' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cronTrigger' while setting bean property 'triggers' with key [0];nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cronTrigger' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Error setting property values;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException;nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'cronExpression' threw exception;nested exception is java.text.ParseException: Unexpected end of expression.
```

Where does it come from ?

A part of my application-context.xml :

```
<!-- Configuration du crontrigger -->
<bean id="schedulerFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail">
        <ref local="exampleJob" />
    </property>

    <!-- run every day at 6AM -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 6 * * ?" />
</bean>
<bean id="exampleJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="fr.web.utils.ExampleJob" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="timeout" value="5" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is you have given reference in Scheduler's trigger  `cronTrigger` which you haven't declare in the XML file.

Provide XML for more detailed answer

**Update**

Your cronExpression isn't seems to be valid
`0 0 6 * * ?` make it `0 0 6 * *  ?` note the last space before `?`

Comment: Well no error anymore. Thanks ! But could you explain the difference between my expression and yours ?

Comment: your expression wasn't just following syntax. it should be separated by space . See [*Cron-Expressions are used to configure instances of CronTrigger. Cron-Expressions are strings that are actually made up of seven sub-expressions, that describe individual details of the schedule. These sub-expression are separated with white-space*](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson06.html)